# Update one table column to populate another table

Tags: java, mysql

So i have two table

**Detail table**

**Name - Admno - ModuleCode - PASS**

John , 127261, 87772, -

candy , 923823, 2323, -

**result table**

**Admno - ModuleCode - PASS**

127261, 87772,Yes

923823, 2323,No

Notice that result table don't have name whereas detail table have and detail table.PASS was not been filled .What i was trying is to fill Detail table column 'PASS' from result table column 'PASS' WHERE both detail.admno = result.admno AND detail.ModuleCode = result.ModuleCode

```
INSERT into detail SET detail.PASS= `result`.PASS FROM
 `result`, detail WHERE `result`.Admno = detail.Admno 
AND `result`.Code = detail.ModuleCode
```

but the error i got was Error code 1064, SQL state 42000: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`FROM` `result`, detail WHERE `result`.Admno = detail.Admno AND `result`.Code = ' at line 1
Line 1, column 1

**By the way I'm using java in netbean to do sql statement.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to have a join statement to combine data from multiple tables.  Below is likely what you're looking for.

```
UPDATE detail INNER JOIN `result` ON `result`.Admno = detail.Admno
AND `result`.Code = detail.ModuleCode SET detail.PASS=`result`.PASS
```